# How to present data in a particular format

Tags: pandas, presentation

I have below table:

```
Date       Age    Income  profession  M/F Marreid/Unmarried
01-Feb-15  20-25  35,000  IT Enginner  M  Unmarried
01-Mar-15  25-30  45,000  IT Enginner  F  Unmarried
01-Feb-15  30-35  50,000  IT Enginner  M  Married
01-Feb-15  35-40  70,000  Doctor       M  Married
01-Mar-15  30-35  15,000  Servent      M  Unmarried
```

There are various filter applied on this e.g. Date/Age/Profession/M-F/Married-Unmarried

All filter values as of now are comming from CSV file. Howver i want to publish the default view as :

```
Date       Income  
01-Feb-15  155,000
01-Mar-15  60,000
```

then based on filter value Date and Income column will be changed.

Comment: Please add reproducible code and well-formatted tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group by `Date` and `Income` and get the sum:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Date')['Income'].sum().reset_index()
```

resulting in:

```
        Date  Income
0  01-Feb-15     155
1  01-Mar-15      60
```

EDIT:

in order to filter the dataframe before getting the sum, just set the filter before grouping:

```
df = df[df['Marreid/Unmarried']=='Married']
```

and then as above:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Date')['Income'].sum().reset_index()
```

resulting in:

```
        Date  Income
0  01-Feb-15     120
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.. I am at Pandas's learner stage. Thanks for corporating on such basics. I have another q: if i want to show another column for Expenditure along with Income. How can i do that?

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked well for your purposes.

Comment: How can i filter this data based on values coming from front end like user may just want to see the data for Females or unmarried males or IT married females.

Comment: Output will be same as given in Question :                                                    Date       Income  
01-Feb-15  155,000
01-Mar-15  60,000                                                                                             Values should be changed based on filter values. Does it make sense?

Comment: I've just updated the answer, please tell me if it is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. This i already did, i also did for many filters(combination of 2 or 3) . How can i implement below conditions: 1) If only one filter is selected e.g. Male then all other filters should take all the values corresponding to Only Male filter 2) If only two filters are selected e.g. Only Male and IT profession are selected.. then all values correspoding to only these two filters should be given.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figured out what you want. Consider to ask a new question with sample input data and desired output.

Comment: Ok.. when i am trying to access the columns (Date, Income) of resulted table ... then it gives me error as Date is not identified. Does using Sum or Group by looses the column names?

Comment: Actually grouping the dataframe lead to have the `Date` as index of the new dataframe, and the `Income` as values. So you can access them through `grouped.index` and `grouped.values`. Hope that helps. I update also the answer with a new way to do it.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also want to draw a Bar graph and Line chart on one. X-axis should list the Date and Bars will show the M and F salaries plotted on Y axis and their expenses as line charts on another Y axis. How can i do that?

Comment: @Rocky please avoid asking new questions in the comments. Consider post another new complete question, thanks.

Comment: I am not able to enter new Questions... as Question was related to same..so thought to post here only.